# Docusign Go live Review failed

Tags: docusignapi

we have an account of DocuSign. we are using java SDK client for sending envelopes. this is all in a demo account. now we want to push integrator key to live. before that, i have to create 20+ transactions. so using Java SDK I have sent envelopes to 20 new clients. but still, when I apply for review it says review failed.

what to do to review integrator key successfully ASAP?
Is using SDK transaction are not valid for a review process?
How can I call API without coding(Postman or API Explorer), That will Work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK Transactions are valid API transactions. Try applying for review without selecting a date and if you still gets an error then contact DocuSign Support or your DocuSign Account Manager who will help you in knowing the reason for failure. Before review make sure that you have developed your integration as per DocuSign API rules and limits - [GO Live](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#go-live)

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue, using Java SDK I made 20+ error-free transactions but the review is failing. I can not submit without selecting the date. support guys are telling to post the question on stack overflow. Could you help?